# Editing a JSON with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a json that looks something this

```
{
"ApiSettings": {
    "EnableSwagger": true,
    "UrlListeners": [
        "http://localhost:9000"
    ],
    "DebugMode":  true
},
}
```

And have some powershell that looks like this:

```
$UrlListeners = "http://(Ipofmymachine):9000"
$JsonFile = Get-Content $destinationDirectory\appsettings.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$JsonFile.ApiSettings.UrlListeners = $UrlListeners
$JsonFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 | Set-Content $destinationDirectory\appsettings.json
```

The issue is that when the PowerShell is ran it converts the UrlListeners in the appsettings.json into a string, whereas it needs to stay as an array. Is there a way to force this value as an array?

Thanks

Comment: You should actually change the item (`[0]`), not the whole (parent) array: `$JsonFile.ApiSettings.UrlListeners[0] = $UrlListeners`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` doesn't change UrlListeners to string,  you do :).

Use this instead:
`$JsonFile.ApiSettings.UrlListeners = @($UrlListeners)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, it will be set as my answer. Would you be able to explain why that works? What is that notation used? I'd like to know the why, not just the how. Thanks

Comment: @user182595 `@()` is array expression operator, it ensures that the output will be an array, even if it's empty or single element

Answer (score 0):

convertfrom-json converts correctly:

```
PS C:\Users\adm> $x = '{
>> "ApiSettings": {
>>     "EnableSwagger": true,
>>     "UrlListeners": [
>>         "http://localhost:9000"
>>     ],
>>     "DebugMode":  true
>> }
>> }' | ConvertFrom-Json

$x.ApiSettings.UrlListeners.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

The problem is that you do:

```
$JsonFile.ApiSettings.UrlListeners = $UrlListeners
```

This changes the datatype to String. You should do:

```
$x.ApiSettings.UrlListeners += $UrlListeners
```

or:

```
$x.ApiSettings.UrlListeners = @($UrlListeners)
```